# Visual Studio 2010 Database Project does not understand Schema Names anymore?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, database-schema, database-project

I just tried to upgrade a Visual Studio 2008 Database project to VS2010 and actually it is quite a mess. Hundreds of warnings, all unsolved references. It seems to boil down to Visual Studio not to understand Schema Names (aka Ownership) anymore. For example, the default dbo schema:

```
[$(MyDataBase)].dbo.MyTable
```

is fine but:

```
[$(MyDataBase)].myschema.MyTable
```

gives an unsolved reference. It did work in VS2008.

Also the abbreviation for dbo, the double dot:

```
[$(MyDataBase)]..MyTable
```

doesn't work anymore.

In the project property windows I restored the references to the correct servers (which were lost after the conversion) but that didn't help.

This seems pretty basic but I don't have a clue how to solve this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There was same major changes between 2008 and 2010 version of Database project on structural perspective in solution e.g. Schemas folder contains subfolders for each schema including dbo.

Solution upgrade doing horrible mess in solution, maybe in SP1 this issue will be resolved.

I suggest to create new DB project and using Schema Compare add existing structure into the project.